# "import xhtml2pdf" suddenly stop working on Google AppEngine standard environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, xhtml2pdf

Few days ago, `import xhtml2pdf` throw *500* server error.
No code updates, no changes.

Here is my code.

```
def get(self):
    import xhtml2pdf
```

Here is the log

```
The process handling this request unexpectedly died. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 203)
```

No more information, I don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So how do you know the import is the problem?

Comment: The 203 error apparently may have many reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgoogle-app-engine%5d%20%27Error%20code%20203%27

Comment: Yes, that is the full code, only one single line.

Comment: Something may have changed on GAE side, making it unhappy with your code. Or just an environment change. Try re-deploying. Try importing something more common instead (`logging` for example). Try writing a response (even an empty one) or just setting the return code - what a typical `get` does. Just to confirm your assumption/find out more.